# C void* Generic Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, pointers

I once tried to make a generic linked list in pure C (no external libraries, only the C standard library) [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/281637/267544) using C macros. With the same restrictions as in the previous attempt, this time I'm trying to use `void*`s.

`linkedlist.h`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
typedef struct LinkedListNode LinkedListNode;

struct LinkedListNode {
    LinkedListNode *next;

    void *data;
};

struct LinkedList {
    LinkedList *this;

    LinkedListNode *head;
    size_t size;

    void (*destructor)(LinkedList *this);
    int (*dataComparer)(void *, void *);
    void (*dataDestroyer)(void *);

    int (*add)(LinkedList *this, void *data);
    void *(*find)(LinkedList *this, bool (*comparer)(void *));
    void (*removeByIndex)(LinkedList *this, size_t index);
    void (*removeByObject)(LinkedList *this, void *object);
    void (*clear)(LinkedList *this);
};

LinkedList *newLinkedList(int (*dataComparer)(void *, void *), void (*dataDestroyer)(void *));
void deleteLinkedList(LinkedList *list);

#endif
```

`linkedlist.c`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"

int ll_default_dataComparer(void *a, void *b) {
    int *castedA = (int *) a;
    int *castedB = (int *) b;

    return *castedA - *castedB;
}

void ll_default_dataDestroyer(void *data) {
    free(data);
}

void ll_default_destructor(LinkedList *this) {
    if (this == NULL) return;

    LinkedListNode *node = this->head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        LinkedListNode *prev = node;
        node = node->next;
        this->dataDestroyer(prev);
    }
}

int ll_default_add(LinkedList *this, void *data) {
    if (this == NULL) return -1;

    LinkedListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    if (newNode == NULL) return -2;

    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = data;

    LinkedListNode *node = this->head;

    if (node == NULL) {
        this->head = newNode;
    } else {
        while (node->next != NULL) node = node->next;
        node->next = newNode;
    }

    this->size++;

    return 0;
}

void *ll_default_find(LinkedList *this, bool (*comparer)(void *)) {
    if (this == NULL) return NULL;

    LinkedListNode *node = this->head;

    while (node != NULL) {
        if (comparer(node->data)) return node->data;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void ll_default_removeByIndex(LinkedList *this, size_t index) {
    if (this == NULL) return;

    if (index >= this->size) return;

    LinkedListNode *prevNode = NULL;
    LinkedListNode *currNode = this->head;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (currNode == NULL) return;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }

    if (prevNode != NULL) {
        prevNode->next = currNode->next;

        this->dataDestroyer(prevNode->data);
    } else {
        this->head = currNode->next;
    }

    free(prevNode);
    this->size--;
}

void ll_default_removeByObject(LinkedList *this, void *object) {
    if (this == NULL) return;

    LinkedListNode *prevNode = NULL;
    LinkedListNode *currNode = this->head;

    while (currNode != NULL) {
        if (this->dataComparer(currNode->data, object) == 0) {
            if (prevNode != NULL) {
                prevNode->next = currNode->next;

                this->dataDestroyer(currNode->data);
            } else {
                this->head = currNode->next;
            }

            free(currNode);
            this->size--;

            return;
        }

        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
}

void ll_default_clear(LinkedList *this) {
    if (this == NULL) return;

    LinkedListNode *prevNode = NULL;
    LinkedListNode *currNode = this->head;

    while (currNode != NULL) {
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;

        this->dataDestroyer(prevNode->data);
        free(prevNode);
    }
}

LinkedList *newLinkedList(int (*dataComparer)(void *, void *), void (*dataDestroyer)(void *)) {
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    list->this = list;
    list->destructor = ll_default_destructor;
    list->dataComparer = dataComparer != NULL ? dataComparer : ll_default_dataComparer;
    list->dataDestroyer = dataDestroyer != NULL ? dataDestroyer : ll_default_dataDestroyer;

    list->add = ll_default_add;
    list->find = ll_default_find;
    list->removeByIndex = ll_default_removeByIndex;
    list->removeByObject = ll_default_removeByObject;

    list->head = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

    return list;
}

void deleteLinkedList(LinkedList *list) {
    list->destructor(list->this);
}
```

`main.c` (testing code, not as rigorously written as the main linked list code):

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"

typedef struct Cake {
    char name[256];
    size_t size;
} Cake;

bool finder(Cake *c) {
    // i forgot c doesn't have lambdas so this is going to be awkward to use
    if (c->size == 69420) return true;
    return false;
}

int compare(Cake *a, Cake *b) {
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}

void destroyCake(Cake *cake) {
    // stub
    //
    // struct Cake has no dynamic allocations, we don't have to do anything
    // to clean it up afterwards
}

void print(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("[\n");

    LinkedListNode *node = list->head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        Cake *cake = node->data;
        printf("\t{ name: \"%s\", size: %zu },\n", cake->name, cake->size);
        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("]\n\n");
}

void cakeprinter(Cake *cake) {
    if (cake == NULL) printf("NULL\n");
    printf("{ name: \"%s\", size: %zu }\n\n", cake->name, cake->size);
}

int main(void) {
    LinkedList *list = newLinkedList(compare, destroyCake);

    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Something went wrong\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Cake *c1 = malloc(sizeof(Cake));
    strcpy(c1->name, "Cakeus Smallus");
    c1->size = 420;

    Cake *c2 = malloc(sizeof(Cake));
    strcpy(c2->name, "Cakeus Enormous");
    c2->size = 69420;

    Cake *c3 = malloc(sizeof(Cake));
    strcpy(c3->name, "Cakeus Tinyeus");
    c3->size = 69;

    Cake *c4 = malloc(sizeof(Cake));
    strcpy(c4->name, "Cakeus Biggus");
    c4->size = 42069;

    list->add(list->this, c1);
    list->add(list->this, c2);
    list->add(list->this, c3);
    list->add(list->this, c4);

    // did we make cakes?
    printf("const cakes = ");
    print(list);

    // can we find a cake?
    Cake *tc1 = list->find(list->this, finder);
    printf("const cake69420 = ");
    cakeprinter(tc1);

    // lets destroy a cake by index and see if it's gone
    list->removeByIndex(list->this, 0); // should be the first cake
    printf("const cakesnoind = ");
    print(list);

    // lets destroy a cake by object and see if it's gone
    list->removeByObject(list->this, tc1);
    printf("const cakesnoobj = ");
    print(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Output as tested with `./main > res.txt`:

```
const cakes = [
    { name: "Cakeus Smallus", size: 420 },
    { name: "Cakeus Enormous", size: 69420 },
    { name: "Cakeus Tinyeus", size: 69 },
    { name: "Cakeus Biggus", size: 42069 },
]

const cake69420 = { name: "Cakeus Enormous", size: 69420 }

const cakesnoind = [
    { name: "Cakeus Enormous", size: 69420 },
    { name: "Cakeus Tinyeus", size: 69 },
    { name: "Cakeus Biggus", size: 42069 },
]

const cakesnoobj = [
    { name: "Cakeus Tinyeus", size: 69 },
    { name: "Cakeus Biggus", size: 42069 },
]
```

The driver code is for quick testing only and is not as rigorously written as the main linked list code is. It compiles with `clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic *.c -o main`, albeit with multiple warnings about incompatible function pointer types (the linked list takes in a function taking void pointers, but I shoved in a function taking pointers to the object I'm trying to store).

As with my previous attempt, looking for feedback for potential improvements.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> potential improvements.

**Merry Christmas**

**Return a flag**

`void *ll_default_find(LinkedList *this, bool (*comparer)(void *))` returns `NULL` when not found.  For a linked list of `void *`, better to not assume `NULL` is available for `ll_...()` use.  Return a flag on success/failure and pass in a place to store the found value.

**Remove functions do not return success indication**

I'd expect something indicating success/failure.

**Extensions**

Consider an *apply* function.  A function that does something to every node in the link-list

I'd expect a `size_t LinkedList_Count(const LinkedList *this);` to return the list count.

**Documentation**

Code, especially `linkedlist.h` lacks documentation.  A good model is to assume the user only sees the .h file.  Express, especially at the high level there, what code does.

**Use `const` for reference data**

When the reference data is not altered, used `const`.  It allows for greater functional use, convey code's intent and helps some compilers.

Example:

```
// int ll_default_dataComparer(void *a, void *b) {
int ll_default_dataComparer(const void *a, const void *b) {
```

**Avoid overflow**

`*castedA - *castedB;` may overflow.  Use a full range compare.  Compilers commonly see the below idiom and emit efficient code.

```
// return *castedA - *castedB;
return (*castedA > *castedB) - (*castedA < *castedB);
```

**-2??**

Functions lack documentation about the meaning of return values like -2 from `ll_default_add(LinkedList)`.

**Out of order code guard**

```
// #include <stdbool.h>
// #include <stddef.h>

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

// Move here
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

**Allocate to the reference object, not type**

Allocate to the referenced object.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// c1 = malloc(sizeof(Cake));
c1 = malloc(sizeof c1[0]);
```

Robust code would check allocation success.

Comment: Re: Return a flag: I am curious, in what circumstance is a `NULL` value for a `void*` not available?

Comment: Re: Remove functions do not return success indication: When adding values, allocation may fail and result in the data not being added, however, when removing, presumably you want the data gone anyway, so it doesn't matter whether it succeeds or fails for whatever reason, as long as the final effect is the data being not present in the list.

Comment: @404NameNotFound `ll_default_find()` returns `NULL` when the item is not found.  It also returns `node->data` which might be `NULL`.  The caller does not know for which reason function returned.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation

Comment: When `ll_default_removeByObject()` does not find the object (or in the index case, out of range), there is no flag to indicate this.  In cases where the Object/index is not certainly in the list, the caller would need to verify objects existence and then potentially delete.  By index, this is not so much an issue.  With `...ByObject()`, it implies 2 passes when one would do if the delete function flagged it success.

Comment: Re: "...it implies 2 passes when one would do if the delete function flagged it success": If the object exists in the list, then it will be deleted. If it doesn't, then it's not there anyway. Either way, the final result is the object the caller wanted deleted is not in the list by the time the call returns. Deleting a non-existent index/object is a no-op with the current implementation by returning early, so no erros would be thrown there. Perhaps I'm missing something that lead to you concluding a return value indicating whether something was actually deleted to be necessary?

Comment: Not absolutely _necessary_, yet useful. Consider if one had multiple `ptr` in the list and wanted to remove all of them, how many time to call `ll_default_find()`?  IOWs, when `ll_default_find()` is called the caller does not certainly know it exist in the list and would find it useful to know if a true deletion occurred.  It certainly does not cost much to return that info.